# What will end up in the variable y after this code is executed (Python) ?

Tags: list, python-2.7

Could someone explain to me this silly question ?

```
x , y = 3, 4
```

Is it going to be a list or a tuple after this execution of the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will only set `x = 3` and `y = 4`. I think this feature is called unpacking. It's really neat and lets you do some interesting things. For instance, you can have a function that returns a tuple of 3 different items, which can be set to 3 different variables:

```
def upack_example():
    return({}, [], 3)

a, b, c = unpack_example()
```

Comment: I think you thought right:   >>> x, y = 1, 3, 4
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
        ValueError: too many values to unpack, the exception said it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could just run it in python interpreter to find out. Anyways, it wont be list, `x` and `y` will end up with respective scalar values

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x, y = 3,4
>>> x
3
>>> y
4
```

To create x and y as list/tuple in single line you can assign

- Tuple `x = y = (3,4)`
- List `x = y = [3,4]`